# Multually exclusive - jwPlayer

Tags: javascript, jquery, jwplayer

```
jwplayer("myElement_0").onPlay(function(){ pausePlayers(1); alert('0 has started'); });
jwplayer("myElement_1").onPlay(function(){ pausePlayers(2); alert('1 has started'); });
jwplayer("myElement_2").onPlay(function(){ pausePlayers(3); alert('2 has started'); });
jwplayer("myElement_3").onPlay(function(){ pausePlayers(4); alert('3 has started'); });
function pausePlayers(playing) { 
    for (var i=0; i<4; i++) {
       if(i != playing) { jwplayer("myElement_"+i).pause(true); }
    }
};
```

I have this script to pause other players if one is running. but it doesn't work. In my console, I see:

`Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'onPlay'
(anonymous function)`

alhouthgh I'm pretty sure the jwplayer script is being loaded, no issues there.

Comment: Check whether `jwplayer("myElement_0")` actually returns a jwplayer object instance, f.e. by logging it to the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some quick and dirty sample code for something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.longtailvideo.com/jwplayer/jwplayer.js"></script>
        <title>Multiple Mutually Exclusive JW6 Players Which Stop at End</title>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#EEE">
            <div id="container"></div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            jwplayer("container").setup({
            file: "http://www.longtailvideo.com/jw/upload/bunny.mp4",
            image: "http://www.longtailvideo.com/jw/upload/bunny.jpg",
            height: 200,
            width: 300,
            stretching: "exactfit",
            events:{
                onPlay: function() {
                jwplayer('container2').stop();jwplayer('container3').stop();
                },
                onTime: function(object) {
                if(object.position > object.duration - 1) {this.pause();}
                }
            }
            });
            </script>
            <br />
            <div id="container2"></div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            jwplayer("container2").setup({
            file: "http://www.longtailvideo.com/jw/upload/bunny.flv",
            image: "http://www.longtailvideo.com/jw/upload/bunny.jpg",
            height: 200,
            width: 300,
            stretching: "exactfit",
            events:{
                onPlay: function() {
                jwplayer('container').stop();jwplayer('container3').stop();
                },
                onTime: function(object) {
                if(object.position > object.duration - 1) {this.pause();}
                }
            }
            });
            </script>
            <br />
            <div id="container3"></div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            jwplayer("container3").setup({
            file: "http://www.longtailvideo.com/jw/upload/bunny.mov",
            image: "http://www.longtailvideo.com/jw/upload/bunny.jpg",
            primary: "flash",
            height: 200,
            width: 300,
            stretching: "exactfit",
            events:{
                onPlay: function() {
                jwplayer('container').stop();jwplayer('container2').stop();
                },
                onTime: function(object) {
                if(object.position > object.duration - 1) {this.pause();}
                }
            }
            });
            </script>
    </body>
</html>
```